# How to execute nexpose ticketing gem scripts from windows server hosting nexpose instance?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jira, nexpose

I am trying to utilize the following gem: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/nexpose_ticketing/1.5.1

The goal is to generate tickets in our Jira instance from the vulnerability reports in Nexpose. Right now we are manually taking the csv from Nexpose and manipulating it in an excel spreadsheet to get the data formatted the way we want before uploading it to Jira.

I have the config files and the necessary scripts (i.e. ticket_service.rb, queries.rb, ticket_repository.rb), but I am not sure how to run these like a program instead of calling each script. The OS running Nexpose is Windows and short of creating a .bat that calls the scripts I am not sure how to get this running. As of right now it is all conceptual and each script does run on its own from a terminal in Ubuntu. I am fairly new to both Ruby and Nexpose so I do not have the foundational understanding of how this gem is suppose to work in real time.

Is there an easier way to accomplish the same goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update. This gem has been deprecated as some of the methods, functions, params, etc have been changed. I believe this was a precursor to Nexpose's Insight VM product functionality.